# Find the next value in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following question was asked in an exam and am totally clueless about how to approach:

If $42\rightarrow26$, $71\rightarrow 78$, $33\rightarrow 16$ then $62\rightarrow $

$1) 68$
 $2) 54$
$3) 38$
$4) 39.$
I couldn't find any pattern. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The answer could be all of the above.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you! But can you explain the logic please?

Comment: Fit with a cubic.

Comment: Thank you so much @ncmathsadist @ projectilemotion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$42\to (4-2)(4+2)=26$$

$$71\to (7-0)(7+1)=78$$

$$33\to (3-2)(3+3)=16$$

$$62\to (6-0)(6+2)=68$$

$$ab\to (a-2)(a+b) $$
$$cd\to (c-0)(c+d) $$
$$ef\to  (e-2)(e+f) $$
...

Comment: Why not alternating.

Answer (score 4):

38

because x, y maps to (x/y), (x+y)

Answer (score 3):

One possible answer is $38.$

How do you get the number associated to $ab?$ Its first digit is $a/b$ and its second digit is $a+b.$